# Cannot connect to SQL DB using PowerShell Stored Credentials from Different User

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, powershell, impersonation

I am writing a small app using PowerShell in order for users to query and in some cases write to a DB. The connection is using a stored credential, which is encrypted in the code and then converted to a secure string. The connection works on my machine, but when opened by another user on their machine, the connection fails. I have tried variations of the following parameters for the $connectionString, which seems to be pointed at by many forums:

`Integrated Security=$FALSE`
`Integrated Security=$TRUE;`
`Integrated ecurity=$SSPI;`
`Trusted_Connection=yes;`
`Trusted_Connection=no;`

My question is whether or not this is possible, or if I am wasting my time and need to build a proxy service to handle these transactions. Thanks in advance.

Here is the errror:

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'first.last@domain.com'."
At line:10 char:1
+ $connection.Open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Comment: Could it be that the credentials are not being used at all, but it works for you because your the account you're logged in with has access via a domain?

Comment: The credentials used are the same as the account I am logged in with. I'll look at that though, as Integrated Security=$FALSE keeps the connection from occurring on my machine, which might even fall on how permissions are allowed on the server. I'll test and get back, thanks.

Comment: To use credentials other than SQL Server logins, you really need to be logged in with those credentials.

Comment: From what I've read so far, I understand that may be the case. But if that is so, then what's the point of being able to declare credentials in the $connectionString if it's just going to use Windows credentials anyway?

Comment: The point of defining credentials in the connection string as far as I have used is for SQL specific accounts that are not associated to a domain. The only time I use SSPI and Trusted Connection is when the authenticating account initiating the query is a Domain account that has the appropriate rights to the target SQL Host\DB

Comment: Yes, and that last part makes perfect sense. So you said _The point of defining credentials in the connection string as far as I have used is for SQL specific accounts that are not associated to a domain_, then if the user is on the domain this does not work?

Comment: I am **User A** and when logged into **Computer A** running this process, the app can query the DB. When **User B** is logged into **Computer B** and they use this app, it uses my credentials for **User A** to connect to the DB, which fails. If an off-domain user tried the same thing it would work? That's just a weird design if you asked me. A non-domain user wouldn't be able to log into our network anyway.

Comment: Are the full credentials encrypted or just the password?  If just the password are you using `[System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::LocalMachine` to encrypt?

Comment: `$GLOBAL:user = "first.last@domain.com"

$GLOBAL:pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "converted password string" (this password works for connectivity to other resources)

$GLOBAL:connectionString = “Server=$GLOBAL:dataSource; Database=$GLOBAL:database; User Id=$GLOBAL:user; Password=$GLOBAL:pwd;”`

Comment: I am thinking my answer lies somewhere in this article: **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231287.aspx**

Comment: @MikeShepard - We're going to create a SQL logon and see how it goes. We're not the admins, so we just need some time to get this created and test it out. If this works, then many thanks.